# lsqnonlin with complex equation systems

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers, nonlinear-optimization

I have two complex-nonlinear equations with two complex variables (then four real variables).
I have tried to use *lsqnonlin* instead of *fsolve* in order to define boundaries (*lb, ub*) to my unknown variables.

```
options=optimset('Display','iter','MaxFunEvals',1e6,'TolX',1e-16);
fun = @myfun;
x0 = [0,0,1000/2,100/2];
lb = [0,0,0,0];
ub = [1,1,1000,100];
x = lsqnonlin(fun,x0,lb,ub,options)
```

My function has this form:

```
function F=myfun(x)

F(1) = a*x(3)+b*x(4)*1i - G1(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4));
F(2) = c*x(3)+d*x(4)*1i - G2(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4));
```

where *a, b, c, d* are constant complex values, and *G(x(1), x(2), x(3),x(4))* is a nonlinear function (with complex components too). After running *lsqnonlin* solver I got this error message: *The Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm does not handle bound constraints and the trust-region-reflective algorithm requires at least as many equations as variables;
aborting.*

First, I am not using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, so I dont think the error is because of that. Then, it makes me think that *lsqnonlin* cannot handle complex equation systems, and maybe it only sees two equations (althought these two complex equations give four real equations to solve my four real variables (*x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)*).

Can I write complex equations system while using *lsqnonlin*? am I doing something wrong? I really would appreciate very much any help you can give me. Thanks a lot in advance))

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the matlab documentation of [`lsqnonlin`](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqnonlin.html#buumikd-6) (Limitations: third point, or search for 'complex'), you can use it for complex-valued problems only without bound constraints. As suggested, you should split `F` into a [real](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) and [imaginary](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imag.html) part as you did for the complex variables.

```
Fc(1) = a*x(3)+b*x(4)*1i - G1(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4));
Fc(2) = c*x(3)+d*x(4)*1i - G2(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4));

F(1:2) = real(Fc);
F(3:4) = imag(Fc);
```

Comment: G(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)) is a complicated nonlinear function to find its real and imaginary analytically, what I have done is to use real(G) and imag(G) to split the equations in real and imaginary parts (so I have four "real" equations). However, it does not seems a efficient way to handle it. If someone know a better way to overcome this, advice me please.

Comment: Why does it not seem an efficient way to handle it?

Comment: Because I am expanding the complicated nonlinear function (G) twice, by simple using matlab's functions real(G) and imag(G).

Comment: F(1) = a*x(3) - real (G1);
F(2) = b*x(4) - imag(G1);
F(1) = c*x(3) - real (G2);
F(2) = d*x(4) - imag(G2);                                                                                    Where actually F still is a "complex" equation since G1 and G2 are indeed complex.